# Error while changing the url of a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, url

I made a mistake in my wordpress website, indeed I changed the url in the general panel. I changed from a .com website to a .fr website without buying the domain name before. 
And now I can not access to my website and got this error : DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

How can I fixed it ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you can either set the following to wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Or in your wp-options table change the values of 
**siteurl** AND **home** using phpmyadmin

Comment: thanks. now, if I buy the new domain name with the .fr extension and that I uptade the value you just write, everything is going to work ? Or i have to change something in the .access or something else ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add these in you wp-config.php file

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Also you can change this in database table wp_options.
in the columns *siteurl* and *home*

Answer (score 1):

look here, you have to change the url manually:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Edit wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```